# Convert javascript json object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I'm building a website with Tornado Websocket and Tornado Websocket accepts this type of json:

```
{"key1":1,"key2":2,"key3":3}
```

I want to papulate element attributes in json and send it to websocket. My javascript:

```
     $(".send").click(function(evt){
                evt.preventDefault();

                var command = $(this).data();
                console.log(command);
                ws.send(command);
        });
```

*command* is json but my websocket does not accept it and throws error when I try

```
#python
json_data  = json.loads(message)
```

Error:

```
03-02 18:09 tornado.application ERROR    Uncaught exception in /ws
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 417, in _run_callback
callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/www/scripts/py/realtime.py", line 102, in on_message
kk  = json.loads(message)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I think that is because I don't need to send a json object, just a string with this syntax like above? Maybe I am wrong, I do not know. Can I  convert  my `$(this).data();` json to the syntax like above or would it be better to produce a string from `$(this).data();` and if yes how ?

Comment: When calling [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) without parameters it returns an object with all the `data-*` attributes. And an object is not JSON.

Comment: Could you `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: *"command is json"* .... no it's not. You are confusing javascript objects and json which is a string representation of those objects

Comment: Can you add a working jsFiddle so we can help you a little better?

Comment: @DuncanTidd yes, thats worked, thank you. I have answered for other people too

Answer (score 2):

@Duncan Tidd was right. I just needed to stringify it.

```
    //html
    <button key1="1"
       data-key2="2"
       data-key3="3"
       data-key4="4"
    type="button"
    class="send btn btn-danger btn-lg">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span></button>

     //javascript
     $(".send").click(function(evt){
                evt.preventDefault();

                var command = JSON.stringify($(this).data());
                console.log(command);
                ws.send(command);
        });


//console
{"key1":"1","key2":2,"key3":3,"key4":4}
```